# Negative step in extended slices doesn't return anything

Tags: python, slice

There is this code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a[2:4:-1] # returns []
a[4:2:-1] # returns [5, 4]
```

Why statement `a[2:4:-1]` returns an empty list altough the range is specified?

Comment: What specific non-empty output did you expect?

Comment: @jamylak none of the answers to that question discuss this situation. A few talk about `a[::-1]` reversing a list, but only gives any examples like this one (where start and end are both given, and step is negative), and another gives the (AFAICT, misleading) 'using a negative step reverses the interpretation of `start` and `end`' (`a[4:2:-1]` contains the value at index 4 and not the one at index 2, as expected under non-reversed interpretation).

Comment: @lvc however they give a very detailed explanation on slicing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you attempt to use `a[2:4:-1]` you try to go backward from list index `2` to `4` which will obviously not work.